# Best way to identify a block with spigot

Tags: minecraft, spigot

What's the best way to create a unique block that's can be identified with spigot?

Something like a id. I want to create a game where you can place items, but I dont know how to identify if the player clicked on the right block. When there's no better way I'll just use the block type/material

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Hashmap to store the blocks Location as key and the players UUID as value, and then check if the UUID of the right-clicking player is equal to the one stored in the Hashmap using the clicked blocks Location.

For example:
In any class it fits, probably your Event Listener:

```
public static HashMap<Location, UUID> blocks = new HashMap<>();
```

Store your data in the HashMap using BlockPlaceEvent in your Event Listener:

```
@EventHandler
public static void onBlockPlace(BlockPlaceEvent event) {
    blocks.put(event.getBlock().getLocation(), event.getPlayer().getUniqueId());
}
```

Check if the player clicked the correct block using PlayerInteractEvent in your EventListener:

```
@EventHandler
public static void onPlayerInteract(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
    if (blocks.get(event.getClickedBlock().getLocation()) != null && blocks.get(event.getClickedBlock().getLocation()) == event.getPlayer().getUniqueId()) {
        // Do whatever you want if player clicked the correct block right here, like:
        event.getPlayer().sendMessage("You clicked the correct block!");
    }
}
```

I hope I was able to help you out!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% what you need, so I have provided two answers I believe could solve your problem, along with some extra information that might be helpful.

### Listener

I believe what you are looking for is a `Listener`. Here is a [link](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/using-the-event-api/) to the Spigot article on how to set one up. I would take a look at it first so you know what a `Listener` is, how it works, and how to add it into your code (if you don't already know).

The particular `Listener` you are looking for is called `PlayerInteractEvent`. It is an event that is called when a player interacts with an object. Here is the [documentation](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/event/player/PlayerInteractEvent.html).

### Specific Block Check

If you simply want to check whether or not a player clicked a specific block, you can use the `getClickedBlock()` and `getType()` methods to do that. I have provided an example implementation of that below. The code checks to see if a player clicks on stone and then performs an action if they have.

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerInteract(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
    if (event.getClickedBlock() != null && event.getClickedBlock().getType() == Material.STONE) {
        // Actions to take here
    }
}
```

### Custom Block Check

Depending on how many unique blocks you are wanting, there are a few different ways you could go about a custom block check. Based on the knowledge I currently have, I'm not 100% sure how to implement these (I just did a little research to find them), but they should suit your needs).

The first method is using a `HashMap`, which allows you to store a key and a value and then access them or reference them. Here is a [link](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/tutorial-hashmaps.269092/) on how to implement them in Spigot.

The other thing you could use is the `Material` class in the Spigot API. Here are the [docs](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/Material.html) for that class.